# Memsql: why memory usage is so high?

Tags: singlestore

Firstly, forgive my poor English.

My test environment :

- [centos 6.5 16G RAM] * 2
- MemSQL Community:MemSQL Ops Server Version:4.1.10  and MemSQL Version:4.1.2
- [my cluster picgure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jvJSh.png)
- [leaf node,top  picgure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CNNRf.png)

---

Yeah, just one master and one leaf. I set maximum_memory = 10G on the leaf node.

Here is the question: Only 334M memory is used for table data, but the leaf node used 13.34G memory. Why is that?

By the way, my use scenario is just like "Speed Test", batch insert and batch delete.

Thank you very much!

## memsql

Answer (score 0):

As noted in the info tooltip next to "Memory", that figure includes cached memory used by MemSQL, that was allocated in the past but isn't being actively used. That's the most likely reason why it would be so much higher than your current table size.

To see where exactly MemSQL is using memory, click on the node in Ops and go to the page for the MemSQL node, there are more details on memory usage there.

Comment: Thank you for your reply.Actually,I met "Linux Out of Memory Behavior" .Even maximum_memory=10G  was setted,the memsql still can use more than 10G memory and the memsql process will be killed by linux.What can i do now?

Comment: A couple questions: Make sure you set maximum_memory on the leaf node - you can check by looking at "show variables" on that node. Also, what is the memory use reported on that node - you can check by running "show status extended" or looking at the node in Ops.

Comment: 1.I am sure maximum_memory=10G on the leaf node. 
2.I list some status：Alloc_table_memory=360.5 MB Alloc_table_metadata_cache=1296.9 MB Buffer_manager_memory=2259.0 MB Malloc_active_memory=16322.7 (+0.0) MB Malloc_cumulative_memory=2826581.1 (+2.5) MB
3.I runned dmesg | grep -i "out of memory",and found linux has killed memsql process three times.
Out of memory: Kill process 18323 (memsqld) score 966 or sacrifice child

Comment: Hmm, it sounds like the problem may be a memory leak. Or, a possibility - are you opening a lot of connections?

Comment: Would it be possible for you to share your test workload?

Comment: 1.Max_used_connections=81,i think the number is not many. 2.My use scenario just like a buffer, batch insert and then caculate and then delete.3.I think the insert operation will allocate memory and the delete operation will free memroy,at least,Redis works like that.4. The max Rows Written is 200/sec,the Rows Read is 100/sec;i think the value is very normal.5.Thank you for your patient.

Comment: Thanks for the information. Delete won't immediately free memory, GC happens in the background. However, based on the mem stats, the problem is not memory allocated for rows. I will do some more investigation. Are your tables rowstore or columnstore?

Comment: Rowstore,i think.I regard memsql as mysql in memory.